# Raspiberry Pi RP2040 LCD clock signals

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I'm using Micro python to try and generate an RGB signal for a TFT screen such as the:
[Screen](https://www.buydisplay.com/5-tft-lcd-display-module-wvga-800x480-high-resolution-for-mp4-gps)

**The timings i need the follow are:**

CLKIN: 3.33Mhz

Horizontal is 800 clock cycles up and 1 clock cycle down

Vertical is 480 Horizontal Clock cycles up and

Ive already got this code that spits out the clock but i cant chnage the square function or add a second state machine, how would i go about bit bashing the pins at the required times.

```
from machine import Pin
from rp2 import PIO, StateMachine, asm_pio
import time

@asm_pio(set_init=PIO.OUT_LOW)
def square():
    wrap_target()
    set(pins, 1)
    set(pins, 0)
    wrap()

    
sm = rp2.StateMachine(0, square, freq=33300000, set_base=Pin(2))

sm.active(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your frequency is 3.33mHz, but each cycle uses 2 cpu cycles so each rising edge is only at 1.665mHz.